# Cross Domain iFrame RequestFullScreen using PostMessage handler

Tags: html, iframe, postmessage

I need to make a parent iFrame on domain A go fullscreen from its postMessage event handler which gets triggered by a postMessage from the window in domain B. I have the postMessage communication setup perfectly. The "allowfullscreen" attribute is set on the iframe too. But the requestFullScreen() method seems to silently quit. After searching I found that due to security reasons, requestFullScreen works only on event handlers for events like mouse clicks,
keypress etc. I tried forcefully executing a click on the iFrame using jquery click() and it comes into the click handler too but the requestFullScreen doesn't work. I tried clicking on the iFrame directly and it goes fullscreen.

How do I make this work?

Here's my code - for the parent on domainA.
**I have made sure that the post message handler is executed when my child on domain B posts a message**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    var container;
    $(function(){
        container = $('#parentFrame')[0];
        container.addEventListener("click",goFullScreen);
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    });

        function receiveMessage(event)
        {
            /*  Use this code to restrict request from  only one particular domain & Port!
             Port not needed in this case*/
            if (event.origin !== "http://myChildDomain.com")
            {
                return;
            }
            /*Retrieving relevant variables*/
            var message=event.data;
            var source=event.source;
            var origin=event.origin;

            //Forcefully generating a click event because fullscreen won't work when directly requested!
            container.click();
        }

    goFullScreen = function (){
        if (container.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            // This is how to go into fullscren mode in Firefox
            // Note the "moz" prefix, which is short for Mozilla.
            container.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (container.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            // This is how to go into fullscreen mode in Chrome and Safari
            // Both of those browsers are based on the Webkit project, hence the same prefix.
            container.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }

</script>
<body>
<iframe id="parentFrame" src="http://myChildDomain/child.html" width="804" height="600" frameborder="0"  scrolling="no" allowfullscreen style="border: 5px solid #00ff00">
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Though never worked with this, from your description I would guess that this might be a _browser level_ security checking: instead of allowing for mouse/key event listener, it only allows within a "small" range after some physical mouse/key input. That kind of make sense too, as every script has the ability to "click" an element.

Comment: I think you're right. Any idea how I could trigger a "small" range event? Or get this working another way? Help appreciated

Comment: If this is considered to be a security concern, then I think you have nothing to do about it, unless you can trick the _browser_ to believe there's a physical click happened.

Comment: hmmm, there has to be another way to make cross domain html containers go fullscreen.